# Rails : Deploy using GoDaddy.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment

I know this is a topic which is very delicate however the simple question is.... has anyone uploaded a rails app using godaddy.com and if so how did they do it. I'm literally clueless. This is my first time. I cannot use anything else due to my clients choice.

Comment: Start here I guess? http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1091/installing-a-ruby-on-rails-application?pc_split_value=3

Comment: You'll probably have more success on http://serverfault.com, stackoverflow is for hands-on programming-related questions. See [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for shared hosting, [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com) is your best bet. Although you will need to make some minor modifications to your application to fit this environment, the benefits are considerable.

I would not recommend using regular shared hosting, which is primarily intended for PHP applications, for Rails. You need a VPS at the very least, and if you're not prepared to manage this, you need a managed environment like Heroku or you'll end up in serious trouble.

For small scale or hobby projects, a 512MB VPS is usually sufficient to get started.

If your client is insisting on GoDaddy, Rails may not be a good choice for you. It does seem possible [according to the documentation](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1091/installing-a-ruby-on-rails-application) but you need to have the correct account type.

Comment: Heroku is the best for ruby on rails (hands down!). Unless you have or you are yourself an expert with servers and rails deployment, I would recommend Heroku to anyone.